# Proving that $\{[-n, n] \mid n \in \mathbb N\} \cup \{\varnothing, \mathbb R\}$ is a topology over $\mathbb R$

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

> Prove that
>   $$\tau = \{[-n, n] \mid n \in \mathbb N\} \cup \{\varnothing, \mathbb R\}$$
>   is a topology over $\mathbb R$ and compare it with the euclidean topology $\mathcal E_1$.

**My attempt**
$\tau_1$ is a topology because it satisfies the definition:

1. $\varnothing, \mathbb R \in \tau$
2. $\tau$ is closed with respect to arbitrary union:
   $$\bigcup_{i \in I} [-n_i, n_i] = [-\max\{n_i\}, \max\{n_i\}] \in \tau$$
3. $\tau$ is closed with respect to finite intersection:
   $$\bigcap_{i = 1}^k [-n_i, n_i] = [-\min\{n_i\}, \min\{n_i\}] \in \tau$$

The euclidean topology $\mathcal E_1$ is finer than $\tau$ because every element of $\tau$ can be written as union of open sets in $\mathcal E_1$:
$$[-n, n] = \bigcup_{k = 2}^{+\infty} B\left(0, n - \frac1k\right);$$
but the converse is not true. Consider the ball $B(2, 1)$: it does not contain $0$, but all the open sets in $\tau$ do.

**The problem**
I think that everything except 2. is correct. Arbitrary union is really bothering me, as I don't think that an infinite sequence of naturals has necessarily a maximum in $\mathbb N$. Can someone shed some light?

Comment: No set of the form $[-n,n]$ is open in the Euclidean topology (as the boundary points are not interior points). Your union formula is wrong, because $n$ and $-n$ are in none of the open balls, so not in the union. So the topologies are not comparable.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Damn, you are right of course. The union results in $(-n, n)$, which is useless. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Glad to help out! At least you're showing work (what many do not do).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(2). as written down, applies in fact only to finite index sets.

But if you look at an infinite sequence of (distinct) natural number than that will contain an unbounded subsequence and the union in that case is $=\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Ok, now I understand. That's why $\mathbb R$ is included in $\tau$ from the start.

Comment: @rubik strictly speaking you should also consider the cases where $\mathbb{R}$ and the empty set are involved in the operations, but these cases are, of course, trivial.

Comment: Right, I forgot those. Thanks!

Comment: Do you think that the part about comparing topologies is correct?

Comment: @rubik yes that looks good to me.